# Code not generating when changing active file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension that generates a prettier config based on your chosen language. Javascript and JSON. The code runs fine on the first document but if you change to another file and try generating clicking the button again. The code fails to start. Is there a way to check if the current document has changed thanks.

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { TextDocument } from "vscode";
import {
    activeEditor
} from "./constants";

var statusBar: vscode.StatusBarItem;

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand("prettier-config.prettierConfig", async () => {
            var changedDocument = false;
            const fileType = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
                "Which file to generate the Prettier Config for?",
                "Javascript",
                "JSON"
            );
            if (fileType === "Javascript" && changedDocument === false) {
                const javascript = activeEditor.edit(
                    (edit: { insert: (arg0: any, arg1: string) => void }) => {
                        edit.insert(
                            new vscode.Position(0, 0),
                            `module.exports = {\n   singleQuote: true,\n   printWidth: 120,\n   tabWidth: 4,\n   trailingComma: all,\n   endOfLine: auto\n};`,
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
            else if (fileType === "JSON" && changedDocument === false) {
                const json = activeEditor.edit(
                    (edit: { insert: (arg0: any, arg1: string) => void }) => {
                        edit.insert(
                            new vscode.Position(0, 0),
                            `{\n   "singleQuote": true,\n   "printWidth": 120,\n   "tabWidth": 4,\n   "trailingComma": "all",\n   "endOfLine": "auto"\n}`,
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        })
    );
    statusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(
        vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right,
        100,
    );
    statusBar.command = "prettier-config.prettierConfig";
    context.subscriptions.push(statusBar);
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(updateStatusBar),
        vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(updateStatusBar),
    );
    updateStatusBar();
}

function updateStatusBar(): void {
    statusBar.text = `$(edit) Prettier Config`;
    statusBar.show();
}

function deactivate() {
    statusBar.dispose();
}
```

Comment: you are not updating the `activeEditor` on each call of the command

Comment: How do I do that? Shall I create a new activeEditor variable or update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the active editor just get it with:

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
```

or use

```
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand
```

it has the active editor as an argument.

To get the changed state of a document use:

```
editor.document.isDirty
```